# Download Google Earth Engine Sentinel Images in High Resolution (Python)

Tags: python, google-earth-engine, satellite-image

I'm trying to download an image from Google Earth Engine sentinel data, but I was only able to get the images at a low resolution.
I used the following code to achieve this:

```
geemap.ee_export_image(image, './download/image.tif', scale=25, region=roi, file_per_band=True)

# Where
# image = image from sentinel colection
```

The scale reduces the image resolution, but if I set it to 1 google prevents me from downloading the image data because its to big.

There is any way to get this imagery data with high resolution?
I used the copernicus hub to download with GUI but I have to create a script using google engine now and I didn't find any way to do that.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sentinel images have an original spatial resolution between 10 m (B2,B3,B4) and 60 m (B1,B9).
Probably that's why they can't be downloaded using lower "scale" parameter.

You can use .reproject() to sample at higher resolution.

```
var image5=image10.reproject({crs:'EPSG:4326', scale: 5})
```